# Magento module SQL install script doesn't run when caches are turned on

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I created an SQL installation script for my extension and it ran just fine. I was developing the extension with the caches turned off. When I turn the caches on, the installation script doesn't get run, and I can't work out why.

I've tried clearing all of the Magento caches through the admin panel, flushing the cache storage, manually removing the contents of the magento/var/cache folder, clearing the APC cache, clearing the redis backend from the command line and restarting the PHP process, and nothing has worked. The only way I've managed to get the installation script to run is by turning the caches off.

Does anyone know why this would be happening? I'm using Magento v1.4.0.0 RC1.

Answer (score 0):

An installation-script should run only once, and only if you tell Magento to do so by updating the version of your modules config.xml. This config gets cached, so clear all your caches and reload a page... It should run the installation script.

You can always reset the way Magento is used to run installscripts, by resetting the version for your module in the database (in the core_resource table of your magento database).

Answer (score 0):

Update scripts are run by Mage_Core_Model_App::_initModules() method, but only when the cache is empty or disabled.

So make sure that you do not access the module configuration in any way before the Mage::run() call in index.php.